# Eclipse - setup for both RIM Blackberry and Android development

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, adt

I installed Eclipse - Version: Helios Service Release 2 on my system (Windows Server 2008).

Then I installed the RIM plugin for RIM development by following - http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp

Then I installed the Android plugin for Eclipse by following - http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

I am trying to run the simple HelloWorld application from Android and I get this error:

Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'HelloWorld'.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/rim/ejde/external/sourceMapper/SourceMapperAccess
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.SourceFile.getContents(SourceFile.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9590)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9562)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:8155)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

I have never done any Java development (I am a core ASP.Net developer) before and I am unable to figure out that while compiling this Android application, somehow the IDE is referencing net/rim/ejde/external/sourceMapper/SourceMapperAccess which I suppose is related to Blackberry libraries.

Any pointers from Eclipse/Blackberry/Android experts will be really appreciated.

Comment: is your project a rim project or an android project ? It's quite rare to want to have a project on both devices and requires a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. BB Eclipse Plugin used to have compatibility issues with other plugins, at least in the past.
Get a fresh new eclipse install for each plugin (eclipse is theoretically a portable app) to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with similar kind of setup.
Following setting in Config.ini change fixed issue:
Change following:
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:net.rim.ejde.preprocessing.hook_1.5.2.201204302029.jar

new setting :

osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:net.rim.ejde_1.5.2.201204302029.jar